# Meta Tag Keywords

Tags: keyword, meta-tags, meta

If I have the keywords "french, toast" will french toast automatically be a keyword applied to my site? Or does it need to be specifically stated. "french, toast, french toast"

Comment: "a keyword applied to my site" by what?

Comment: Indexing, search terms, etc. I understand keywords do not play anywhere near as important of a role as they used to, but I am still curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#meta-keywords), the value "must be a set of comma-separated tokens, each of which is a keyword relevant to the page".

In the example you can see that a token can include a space (in "`type face`"):

> ```
> <meta name="keywords" content="british,type face,font,fonts,highway,highways">
> ```

So for this example the algorithm would add the following items to the *keywords* list:

- british
- type face
- font
- fonts
- highway
- highways

Strictly speaking, these are not keywords:

- font highway
- british type face
- face
- …

So yes, you'd have to explicitly state combinations of keywords (if they make sense). "Stack" and "Overflow" is not equivalent to "Stack Overflow".

**However**, depending on the implementation of the consuming user-agent, this might not be needed, as some user-agents will probably throw all keywords into a basket anyway.